# What happen during processing

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Maybe this is a dummy question, This is the scene.

I've got a web system (ASP.NET MVC 2.0). When I press the "Save" button all the process it's call and begin the execution. What happen if I:

```
1) Press another link to change view
2) Press again the submit button
```

Both scenes whereas the process not finish yet.

Regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first controller (that handles the button)  probably got the action, and then another controller got an action (from the link, if it's to the same site), and then the first controller gets the button action again.

your browser aborts the calls, but **they are run in the server.**

eventually the browser shows you the last result from the call that was not aborted.

If you want to observe this behavior use a debugger - and see the actions called.. and firebug - to see the browser aborts...

Comment: But after you click save, it goes to the controller `ActionResult`. At this point if you click a different link, the Controller still finishes that action, or does it aborts? Could you please eloborate, thanks!

Comment: @VoodooChild: Remember that each request your browser makes is handled separately - even if they come from the same user/browser.  The behaviour would depend on your specific code, but quite probably you'd find that you have one instance of the controller for each click - and each would complete its actions.  The server isn't told that your browser has aborted the request, so it just completes what it's been asked to do.

Comment: The controller finishes that action.The results is sent to the emptiness of the web :-) (that request is aborted...)

Comment: So the data could be duplicated in my system, because the database gives a new ID for primary key.